# How To Set Ajax Url with Variable

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i want to add some string to the url in ajax process, but fail every time i access the function.
when i submit the form it only access this url 'Master_data/'

```
var jenis_submit = document.getElementById('jenis_submit');
var submit_url = '';
if (jenis_submit == '1') {

    submit_url = "func_save_instansi";
} else if (jenis_submit == '2') {

    submit_url = "func_update_instansi";
}

$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>Master_data/' + submit_url,
    method: 'POST',
    data: dataKirim,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        // console.log(data);
        $('#notif').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: show your controller function. also check `submit_url`  before ajax call that it has proper value or not

Comment: Debug the code and see what do you get in the variable "submit_url", use console.log

Comment: Make sure that submit_url variable gets overwritten in any of the if else conditions, bcoz if it will not enter any condition, then ofcourse will be taken as a blank string as u have initialized it to ''

Comment: just check the value of jenis_submit in console.It's maybe because jenis_submit value not in 1 or 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get value by id with javascript like this,

```
//var number = document.getElementById("number").value; //in your code `.value` is missing

var jenis_submit = document.getElementById('jenis_submit').value;
var submit_url = '';
if (jenis_submit == '1') {

    submit_url = "func_save_instansi";
} else if (jenis_submit == '2') {

    submit_url = "func_update_instansi";
}
```

then
Replace your code with this

```
url: "<?php echo base_url('master_data/'); ?>" + submit_url,
```

Comment: And what will that do ? `<?php echo base_url();?>` means that it it the previous part of the url i.e. before "Master_data/" and that could be anything

Comment: suppose `master_data` is his controller and `submit_url` is function so it will create `localhost/prjname/master_data/function_name`

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the php value to a js variable and concat both

```
var url = '<?php echo base_url();?>Master_data/';
```

and then in ajax

```
url: url + submit_url,
```

**UPDATED:**

I missed one other mistake in your code

```
var number = document.getElementById("number").value; //in your code `.value` is missing
```

as mentioned in the above(M.Hemant)'s answer.

Comment: That doesnot seems to make any difference. What you are doing is just declaring a variable differently and then using it in ajax...There is no difference in your and Reza's code then

Comment: no in ajax the url think as completed when it gets a ending single quotes. thats why he is not getting that variable. so I try to assign it to a new variable and complete the url with concat

Comment: I too faced this kind of situations. let him try this and get back to us with his replies...

Comment: Ok let him try and we shall conclude later if its even a case ever.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var jenis_submit = document.getElementById('jenis_submit');
var submit_url   = '';

if (jenis_submit == '1') {
    submit_url = "func_save_instansi";
} else if(jenis_submit == '2') {
    submit_url = "func_update_instansi";
}

var post_url = '<?php echo base_url('Master_data'); ?>' + '/' + submit_url;

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: post_url,
     data: dataKirim,
     beforeSend: function() {
       // you can show a preloader here
     }
 }).done(function(data) {
     // hide the preloader
     // console.log(data);
     $('#notif').html(data);
 }).fail(function() { 
   // hide the preloader
   // show an error message
 });
```